# Interesting walking activities in Narita on an overnight stop

Tags: layovers, walking, nrt

I'd like to hear about pleasant hotels near interesting walks or other activities in Narita. We are going to be on a long trip between North America and Asia, but plan to take about a day at a Narita-area hotel between legs of our flights.

Our goal is not simply to have a cheap airport hotel room, but to be able to enjoy a few hours on foot outside in the Narita area between our flights — nothing strenuous, but enough to get fresh air and a little exercise. We'll have a full afternoon and evening on the ground each time we're there, so we'd like to be well within reach of good walking and (of secondary importance) shopping.

As an example, we once stayed at an airport hotel that was a short walk away from a [small forest and cemetery](http://goo.gl/DmshMM), which brought us serendipitous happiness for an hour. I remember that there is a large mall in Narita and also a tourist-oriented shopping street, and I suppose most of the hotels provide transportation there. But it's very hard to tell from my desk in New York what else might be easy to get to from the many Narita hotels.

Comment: Are you dead set on Narita?  Ueno in central Tokyo is 36 min away by train, and offers a massive park sprinkled with shrines and museums to explore.

Comment: Thanks; yes, in part because we'll be recuperating from a long-haul flight to Japan, and in part because we'd we'd rather be in a smaller city or town, we'd like to be in Narita. Beyond hotels proper, I know there are also _ryōkan_ everywhere, but I have no idea how to find a suitable one.

Comment: Narita has >100k people and is effectively a suburb of Tokyo.  There are *very* few actual ryokan anywhere near Tokyo, although not a few cheap places use the name to pull in foreign tourists.

Comment: For Ryokan suggestions try www.japaneseguesthouses.com.  They have organized Ryokan accommodation in Narita town for me in the past (it has been a few years since my last stay & unfortunately the Ryokan name escapes me).

Answer (score 8):

The Narita Shinsoji Temple is quite close (8 minutes by train) to Narita airport and is quite delightful. Before Narita Airport was made, it was the main attraction in the area.

You want to take the JR or Keisei train from "Narita Airport" to "Narita Station".

You can access the temple website here: http://www.naritasan.or.jp/english/